# Quickbooks web connector error

Tags: php, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I had a working setup of desktop QuickBooks and my website PHP application so far. Recently I decided to restore a backup of a different company file in my QuickBooks.

It restored successfully, but now when I try to add a new application in QuickBooks web connector using a new username and password (I've already changed the username/password in `web_connector.php` and cleared all database entries relevant to QuickBooks tables) and run "update" on this newly added application, I get the error

> Invalid password for username: mudit

I've rechecked and readded the  application several times and checked my web connector file as well. They all have the new username and password.

Please let me know what else to change or what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you try changing the credentials in the `*.qbwc` file? Remember the username/password in QuickBooks is **not** the same as the credentials needed for the `web_connector.php` file. EDIT: Saw your mention of the web connector file. There's something missing so definitely try and check again. Also try changing the ID values by a couple of characters.

Comment: Yes i tried changing id value and even readded the .QWC file but no luck....This is the error message i see in error window in web connector

    Version:
    PHP QuickBooks SOAP Server v2.0 at /quickbook/web_connector.php

    Message:
    Invalid password for username: mudit
    Description:
    QBWC1040: Web connector did not provide a valid password for the      given username. Job ending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the Web Connector says, you have an:

> Invalid password for username: mudit

This:

> ... and cleared all database entries relevant to QuickBooks tables ...

Is a *major* red flag, since the username/password are *stored in the very QuickBooks tables that you have cleared*.

If you cleared those tables, then you probably cleared your username and password.

Look in the `quickbooks_user` SQL table - is your username/password in there? If not, then you deleted your username/password, and you need to re-add them to that table.

Comment: @user3634504 Listen to this man, he wrote the QB PHP framework you're using. Excellent work on this project by the way, it's a godsend

Comment: Thank you keith...yes i dropped all tables related to quickbook and it worked after that :)

Comment: what encryption they use to save password. md5 or SHA1. becuse i have tested with both and it says invalid password

Comment: Use this method to store the username/password: https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector.php#L251

Comment: QuickBooks_Utilities::createUser($dsn, $user, $pass);